# seconds are lost when datetime transferred from flutter to firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am saving documents in firestore using datetime as their id but if I saved more than one in the same minute it deletes the old one and replace it with newest one "in the same minute"
I check the date time in flutter it has seconds and milliseconds
but in firestore it's only minutes and seconds and milliseconds are set to 00:000

meaning 2020-12-04 13:51:03.836035 in flutter turns to 2020-12-04 13:51:00.000  in firestore

how can I solve this?

I use

```
users
    .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
    .collection('documents')
    .doc(dateTime.toString())
    .set({
      'day': DateTime.parse(dateTime.toString().substring(0, 10)),
      'document': {
        dateTime.toString(): {'documentContent': content.text, 'documentDateTime': dateTime}
      }
    }, SetOptions(merge: true))
    .then((value) => print("Document Added"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add Document: $error"));
```

dateTime is a DateTime object btw

I am talking about this part 'documentDateTime': dateTime or dateTime.toString()

Comment: It looks like your .substring(0, 10) trims the time off the date? If you remove this, does it change anything?

Comment: I see this but I am talking about this part

'documentDateTime': dateTime 
or
dateTime.toString()

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. So what happens when you debug and get the value of the document (`dateTime.toString()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the code you shared to create a document and then I have downloaded the documents back to Flutter app and printed it's contents and here's what I get:

```
// Add code right below your snippet
users
    .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
    .collection('documents')
    .doc(dateTime.toString())
    .get()
    .then((doc) => print(doc.data()));

// Output:
{document:
  {2020-12-18 13:49:58.496955: 
    {documentContent: xx,
     documentDateTime: Timestamp(seconds=1608299398, nanoseconds=496000000)}},
 day: Timestamp(seconds=1608249600, nanoseconds=0)}
```

Indeed the field `documentDateTime` has the milliseconds data. What happens is that the Firestore Console UI doesn't show milliseconds data even though the data is there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**I strongly recommend not using date strings as document IDs.**  This is causing you trouble today, and will continue to cause you trouble in the future.

Instead, store the time as a field in the document (in whatever format you find most convenient), and use that field to query and order the documents.  When creating the document, you can take the random document ID provided by `add()`.

If you need to update something in that document, you can use the fields of the document to locate it with a query, then update the document after you find it.  It is up to you to figure out how best store the time so that you can locate the document again.  This is something you will need to think through carefully.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but I already have a field in the document for the DateTime object but seconds are not registered just 00:000, how can I solve that?

Comment: You stripped them out with substring(0,10).  If you don't want that, then remove that code.  You will have to define exactly what you want to store, then make sure your code matches that.  If you want help with that here, you should edit the question to explain in more detail what doesn't work the way you expect, showing specific examples.